# Frama-C development with eclipse: autocompletion not working in some cases

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, ocaml, frama-c

I am developing a Frama-C plugin. I use Eclipse for the development.
If I write "normal" OCaml-function-calls (of own functions and system-functions), the tooltip shows me available functions. 
For example: if I type `String.i` eclipse provides `String.iter` and other functions as possibilities in a box.

If I want to call a frama-c function, like `Ast.g` for `Ast.get()`, or `Db.Value.`, this doesn't work that way, no information of matching functions is provided.

Is it possible to activate that?

Comment: Have you configured your project so that Eclipse knows where are the souces (or the interface) of the Frama-c functions?

Comment: I added /usr/share/frama-c and /usr/lib/frama-c to the Project Paths of the project's properties. I didn't find other path that are Frama-C specific on my system. I don't know if the path has to be more specific, or if there are other path to the sources.

Comment: And have you specified that you use a library with Frama-C functions ? (paths are one thing, libraries are an other one)

Comment: Now I tried to add the paths to Project-Properties -> Project->Libraries. This also didn't work. Adding it to Linked Resources didn't solve the problem either. Am I at the right place? Or do I have to add it somewhere else? 
Btw: When executing the framework with the plugin as parameter, it works, but it is just hard to code without really knowing which functions are available.

Comment: I am sure sure it is the right way, but I would try to install the sources of Frama-C and indicate them in the project (not as sources for the project but as sources of the libraries).

Comment: Now I have added a specific file in the project's properties (ast_data.ml). When calling Ast., it now provides the functions. That means I am on the right way. 
Furthermore, if I add the folder that contains the file directly, it also works. 
But if I add the folder that contains the folder that contains the file, it doesn't work. That is bad, because frama-C contains many subfolders, and i want tips for every function and not include all paths to every plugin I develop. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a solution that works for me:

1. I downloaded the sources from the Frama-C site.
2. I copied the content of the src-folder to /usr/src/frama-c
3. I added a folder to my project (in the directory where my own .ml-files are located)
4. When creating -> click on advanced -> "Link to alternate location"
5. Here, I defined /usr/src/frama-c as location
6. After clicking on Finish, the autocompletion for the frama-c-functions are available.

->Goal reached.

Possible Problems for others:
Update of the framework -> The sources will not be updated, because manually added -> Functions may be not provided (not relevant for me, project not big enough that there are lots of framework-changes)

Thanks Lucky J. for the help :)